# Como posso pegar valores de vários checkbox selecionados e enviar como um List para o Spring MVC?

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Tudo bem? Estou com uma dúvida, estou desenvolvendo um sistema utilizando Spring MVC e HTML 5 na View,e como renderizador estou utilizando o thymeleaf.

Estou tentando pegar todos os valores selecionados de um conjunto de checkbox que representam os dias da semana: segunda, terça até sexta e gostaria de saber como faço para pegar todos os valores desses checkbox selecionados e enviar como uma List para meu controller? Abaixo o código da View:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" >
     <label class="checkbox-inline" th:each="dia : ${todosDiaDaSemana}" >
            <input type="checkbox" th:value="${dia.nome}" th:text="${dia.nome}" name="dias" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Abaixo segue a entity Turma:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "turma")
public class Turma {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(length = 80, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(length = 6)
private String horarioInicial;

@Column(length = 6)
private String horarioFinal;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DiaDaSemana> dias = new ArrayList<>();

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
private Escolaridade escolaridade;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 20, nullable = false)
private Disciplina disciplina;

// methods getters and setters
...
}
```

Abaixo segue o entity DiaDaSemana:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dia_da_semana")
public class DiaDaSemana {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NaturalId
@Column(length = 7, nullable = false)
private String nome;

// methods getters and setters
...
}
```

Comment: O que é "dia"? Uma classe própria que representa os dias da semana, uma `String`, alguma outra coisa?

Comment: Eu tenho uma Entity turma que possui um atributo List<DiaDaSemana> e outra Entity DiaDaSemana, conforme a seguir:                            **@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<DiaDaSemana> dias = new ArrayList<>();**

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e adicione a classe `DiaDaSemana` por favor.

Comment: Já está editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar a anotação `@RequestParam` e informar o nome do parâmetro, que no seu caso é o valor do campo `name` no `input type="checkbox"`.

```
//Altere o value e method de acordo com o necessário
@RequestMapping(value="caminhoDoMeuFomulario", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(@RequestParam("dias") List<String> dias) {
        //aqui você faz o processamento que quiser
    return "seujsp";
}
```

Caso você queira aproveitar melhor o que [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) pode fazer, dê uma olhada [nesse](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html) tutorial de integração entre ele e o Spring MVC. Existe um exemplo completo que inclui o que você quer e bem mais!

---

Edit:

No seu caso não da certo porque você quer vincular um objeto a um `checkbox`. Para você fazer isso, você deve implementar um `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter`. Devido a forma que você mapeou suas entidades, implementar essa interface talvez não seja a melhor opção, seria melhor alterar um pouco o seu mapeamento. Mostrarei as duas opções e que você escolha a que achar melhor.

### Alterando o Mapeamento:

Como os dias da semana são uma constante, você poderia transformá-los em uma enumeração. Ficaria assim:

DiaDaSemana

```
public enum DiaDaSemana {
    DOMINGO("Domingo"),
    SEGUNDA_FEIRA("Segunda-feira"),
    TERCA_FEIRA("Terça-feira"),
    QUARTA_FEIRA("Quarta-feira"),
    QUINTA_FEIRA("Quinta-feira"),
    SEXTA_FEIRA("Sexta-feira"),
    SABADO("Sábado");

    private final String nome;

    private DiaDaSemana(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Sua classe `Turma` ficaria assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "turma")
public class Turma {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=DiaDaSemana.class)
    @CollectionTable(name="turma_diaDaSemana")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="dia", nullable=false)
    private Set<DiaDaSemana> diasDaSemana;

    // Seus outros atributos
    // methods getters and setters
}
```

Sua `View`(não se esqueça de altera `todosDiasDaSemana` para que ele reflita os valores da enumeração. Para obter todos os valores da enumeração basta chama o método `DiaDaSemana.values()`):

```
<div class="col-sm-4" >
    <label class="checkbox-inline" th:each="dia : ${todosDiaDaSemana}" >
        <input type="checkbox" th:value="${dia}" th:text="${dia.nome}" name="diasDaSemana" />
    </label>
</div>
```

No seu `Controller`:

```
//Altere o value e method de acordo com o necessário
@RequestMapping(value="caminhoDoMeuFomulario", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(Turma turma) {
        //aqui você faz o processamento que quiser
    return "seujsp";
}
```

### Implementando um Converter:

DiaDaSemanaConverter:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class DiaDaSemanaConverter implements Converter <String, DiaDaSemana> {

    @Override
       public DiaDaSemana convert(String source) {
        return new DiaDaSemana(source);
    }
}
```

Registre o ser `DiaDaSemanaConverter` no Spring:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentSca
public class SpringFrameworkConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    //Os outros métodos

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new DiaDaSemanaConverter());
        super.addFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```

Sua View (o valor do atributo `name` deve ser igual ao do seu setter sem o prefixo "set", exemplo: se seu método se chama `setDiasDaSemana` o atributo `name` deve ser `diasDaSemana`):

```
<div class="col-sm-4" >
    <label class="checkbox-inline" th:each="dia : ${todosDiaDaSemana}" >
        <input type="checkbox" th:value="${dia.nome}" th:text="${dia.nome}" name="diasDaSemana" />
    </label>
</div>
```

No seu `Controller`:

```
//Altere o value e method de acordo com o necessário
@RequestMapping(value="caminhoDoMeuFomulario", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(Turma turma) {
        //aqui você faz o processamento que quiser
    return "seujsp";
}
```

Comment: No meu caso, eu gostaria de salvar o objeto Turma e automaticamente ele converter todos os campos para atributos do mesmo, mas quando coloco esse parâmetro a mais diz que não conseguiu converter um array de Strings para o valor correto do atributo.

Comment: @OsmaeldeSousaBraga Editei a resposta e adicionei possíveis soluções para o seu problema.

Comment: muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, estou iniciando agora no desenvolvimento web com Spring e tenho muito a aprender ainda, mas com ajuda de pessoas como você que a comunidade segue em frente. Vlw, abraço.